# How to get last day of last week in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to get last date of the lastweek in sql? I mean last sunday date using query?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Regardless of the actual DATEFIRST setting, the last Sunday could be found like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,
               -1 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,
               GETDATE()
              ) AS LastSunday
```

Replace `GETDATE()` with a parameter `@date` to get the last Sunday before a particular date.

Comment: Wow, I thought I was so clever when I came up with that modulus trick last week for finding the next Friday after a given date.  I salute you, sir.  For the non-math geeks out there, Andriy is returning the number of days since Sunday by using a remainder.  I'm giving a big thumbs up!

Answer (score 24):

**Last Sunday** (*Which is the end of "last week"*)

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6) AS LAST_SUNDAY
```

**This Week** (*Assuming Mon-Sun Week Format*)

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 7) AS START_OF_WEEK
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6 + 7) AS END_OF_WEEK
```

**Results**

```
START_OF_WEEK
-----------------------
2011-05-02 00:00:00.000

END_OF_WEEK
-----------------------
2011-05-08 00:00:00.000
```

**Examples to explain the voodoo** (*Use this to change above SQL to your desired Week Starting and Week Ending day-of-week*)

- The examples below locate days of the week within the current week (Sunday to Saturday)
- If the actual END_OF_WEEK is next Sun-Sat week, then you need to +7 to this week's value.  (See the END_OF_WEEK example above.)

*SQL Below*

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), -2) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Saturday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), -1) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Sunday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Monday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 1) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Tuesday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 2) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Wednesday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 3) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Thursday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 4) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Friday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 5) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Saturday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Sunday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 7) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Monday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 8) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Tuesday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 9, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 9) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Wednesday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 10, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 10) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Thursday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 11, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 11) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Friday */
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 12, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 12) AS DAY_OF_WEEK /* Saturday */
etc...
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a great article on how to do this:

http://www.objectreference.net/post/SQL-Find-last-week-date-range.aspx

You would want to use the @StartOfPrevWeek variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @LastSunday DATETIME 

-- This will get the previous Sunday with time as 23:59:59 
SELECT @LastSunday = Dateadd(SECOND, -1, Dateadd(WK, Datediff(WK, 6, 
                                                     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                                                , 7)) 

SELECT @LastSunday 

-- This gets the monday prior to it and time of 00:00:00 
SELECT Dateadd(SECOND, 1, Dateadd(DAY, -7, @LastSunday)) 
-- This will make you time spans between eg, Monday 16/07/2012 00:00:00 through to Sunday 22/07/2012 23:59:59
-- Then use them in your WHERE clause like this 
-- SELECT X,Y,Z From SomeTable 
-- WHERE DateField BETWEEN @PreviousMondayToLastSunday AND @LastSunday
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the previous sunday, or today if today is sunday, try this

```
DATEADD(day,- (DATEPART(dw,getdate()) + @@DATEFIRST -1) % 7, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is more straightforward with a suitable calendar table. No voodoo.

```
select max(cal_date) end_of_last_week
from calendar
where (cal_date < current_date and day_of_week = 'Sun');

end_of_last_week
--
2011-05-01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (DATEADD(DAY, ((DATEPART(dw, @Date) - 1) * -1), @Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the next and precious Friday from a given date and time

```
DECLARE @PREVIOUS int, @dtmStart datetime,@dtmEnd datetime, @NEXT int;
SET @dtmStart = '12/10/2013';
SET @dtmEnd = '12/11/2013';

select @PREVIOUS = datepart(dw,@dtmStart)
 WHILE @PREVIOUS <> 6
BEGIN 
    SET @dtmStart = DATEADD(day , -1 ,@dtmStart)
    SET @PREVIOUS = datepart(dw,@dtmStart)
  CONTINUE 
END 
select @dtmStart

 SELECT @NEXT = DATEPART(dw, @dtmEnd)
   WHILE @NEXT <> 6
BEGIN 
    SET @dtmEnd = DATEADD(day , 1 ,@dtmEnd)
    SET @NEXT = datepart(dw,@dtmEnd)
  CONTINUE 
END 
select @dtmEnd
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to get the date of last Saturday. This method is independent of settings of the database.

```
declare @lastSaturday date,
        @today date,
        @todayName varchar(20);

select  @todayName = datename(weekday, getdate()), @today = getdate();

select  
            case @todayName 
                when 'Saturday' then @today
                when 'Sunday' then dateadd(day,-1,@today)
                when 'Monday' then dateadd(day,-2,@today)
                when 'Tuesday' then dateadd(day,-3,@today)
                when 'Wednesday' then dateadd(day,-4,@today)
                when 'Thursday' then dateadd(day,-5,@today)
                when 'Friday' then dateadd(day,-6,@today)
            end  as LastSaturday;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()-DatePart(dw, GETDATE());
```

Comment: This does not return the proper date.  Running it now returns 4/30, which is last Saturday.