# Problem with grouping on european standard week and year

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, iso

There is a datepart iso_week returning the iso_week for a selected day.

SELECT DATEPART(iso_week, getdate())

This will return the european standard for week current. It is not nessasarily the same as week.

Here comes the tricky part:

```
SELECT DATEPART(iso_week, '2011-01-01')
```

Returns

```
52
```

so it belongs to last year
In order to group by year and iso_week, I need to consider that iso_week is not from the same year.

Iso_week starts on monday and belongs to the year where most days overlap. So 4 days in 2010 and 3 days in 2011, the week is 52 and all days belong to iso_year 2010. However TSQL doesn't have the detepart iso_year.

```
declare @t table(col1 datetime)

insert @t 
ALL SELECT '2010-12-28'
UNION ALL SELECT '2010-12-29'
UNION ALL SELECT '2010-12-30'
UNION ALL SELECT '2010-12-31'
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-01-02'
--UNION ALL SELECT '2011-01-03' Stackexchange is bugged and can't handle this line showing 53
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-01-04'
```

I need something like (iso_year doesn't exist):

```
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, col1) WEEK, DATEPART(iso_YEAR, col1) YEAR, COUNT(*) COUNT 
FROM @t
GROUP BY DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, col1), DATEPART(iso_YEAR, col1)
ORDER BY  2,1
```

Expected result

```
WEEK  YEAR          COUNT
52    2010           6
1     2011           2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same ISO week's Thursday will unambiguously provide you with the correct year. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924777/how-to-get-last-day-of-last-week-in-sql/5925176#5925176) can provide you with the idea how to obtain the right Thursday from the given date.

```
SELECT
  Week  = DATEPART(ISOWK, TheThursday),
  Year  = DATEPART(YEAR, TheThursday),
  Count = COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT
    TheThursday = DATEADD(
      DAY,
      3 - (DATEPART(DW, col1) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,
      col1
    )
  FROM @t
) s
GROUP BY
  TheThursday
```

Comment: Very nice, took care of the problem without setting firstdate and took care of both higher and lower week breaks. Also describing the calculation with TheThursday. Take a peek at my version as well please.

Answer (score 1):

You can check against `dayofyear` and `iso_week` to figure out if you need to subtract year with 1 or not.

```
select datepart(iso_week, col1) as [week], 
       case when datepart(dayofyear, col1) < 7 and
                 datepart(iso_week, col1) > 51
            then year(col1) - 1
            else year(col1)
       end as [year], 
       count(*) as [count]
from @t
group by datepart(iso_week, col1),
         case when datepart(dayofyear, col1) < 7 and
                   datepart(iso_week, col1) > 51
              then year(col1) - 1
              else year(col1)
         end
order by [year], [week]
```

Comment: It is a decent solution, but it is going to be a long statement when also taking care of dates like '2008-12-31' which is actually week 1. Andriy came up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Edited...

```
SELECT 
  IsoWeek  = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, TheDate), 
  IsoYear  = CASE 
    WHEN 
      MONTH(TheDate) = 1 AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, TheDate) > 51 
      THEN YEAR(TheDate) - 1 
      ELSE YEAR(TheDate) 
    END, 
  DayCount = COUNT(*)
FROM 
  @t
GROUP BY 
  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, TheDate), 
  CASE 
    WHEN MONTH(TheDate) = 1 AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, TheDate) > 51 
    THEN YEAR(TheDate) - 1 
    ELSE YEAR(TheDate) 
  END 
ORDER BY  
  IsoYear,
  IsoWeek

--IsoWeek  IsoYear  DayCount
--     52     2010         6
--      1     2011         2
```

Comment: No good. Some ISO Years have 53 weeks. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). Otherwise this looks nice.

Comment: Corrected.  Thanks for spotting the defect Chris.

Answer (score 1):

This solution also handles years where the week start the year before.

```
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, col1) WEEK, 
DATEPART(year , col1 - CAST(col1-.5 as int)%7 + 3) YEAR, 
COUNT(*) COUNT 
FROM @t
GROUP BY DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, col1), 
DATEPART(year , col1 - CAST(col1-.5 as int)%7 + 3)
ORDER BY 2,1
```

Comment: Using `weekday` makes you dependent on `set datefirst` setting. You could probably use `@@datefirst` to fix that.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson I changed my answer so it doesn't use datefirst. Found a better way. I think you will find it interesting

Comment: Ultimately you seem to be using Thursdays too, only you took a different route to come to that solution. I think this is a clever way of taking advantage of the internal representation of dates in SQL Server. I'd hesitate putting this in production code for my company, but I usually do not mind benefiting from such concise, smart solutions in some little projects of my own. One thing: if `col1` can ever have a chance to be `date` instead of `datetime`, you'll need to add some changes to make it work (`date` is incompatible with `int`).

Comment: *Andriy I was planning to put this in a function. That is why i was desperately trying to avoid 'set datefirst 1' (which can't be done in functions). I assume that passing a date into a datetime function will work fine.