# Isoweek in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

In SQL Server 2008 the isoweek can be found with this:

```
SELECT datepart(iso_week, getdate())
```

Before SQL Server 2008 there were no built-in function to find isoweek.

I have been searching high and low for a good syntax to find a userdefined iso_week for SQL Server  2005. I found quite a few solutions. Didn't like any of the solutions I found, most of them didn't work, and they were way too long.

Since the issue is very old, I would expect this issue is depleted and the best solution has been found. I was unable to find a good method though.

I wrote a solution, which I am going to post later. But before I do, I want to make absolutely sure that no one else can match the solution I wrote.

I am hoping to earn the self-learner badge. I urge people to find the best answers out there for this ancient question.

I am going to post my answer after giving people a chance of finding a good solution.

Comment: Along with the week number it is important to include the ISO week year, because it can differ from the normal date year. That seems to be non-trivial.

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter link to iso_year [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829604/what-is-iso-year-in-sql-server/22830524#22830524)

Comment: I already found your answer there, good to make other readers aware.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an approach that is similar to yours in that it also relies on this week's Thursday. But in the end it uses the date differently.

1. Get the date of this (ISO) week's Thursday.

   Your own solution uses the hard coded date of a known Thursday. Alternatively, this week's Thursday could be found with the help of `@@DATEFIRST`:

   ```
   SELECT Th = DATEADD(DAY, 3 - (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @date) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7, @date)
   ```

   (I wasn't struggling too much for the right formula because it was [already known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924777/how-to-get-last-day-of-last-week-in-sql/5925176#5925176) to me.)
2. Get the Thursday's day of year:

   ```
   SELECT DY = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, Th)
   ```
3. Use the number to find out the week like this:

   ```
   SELECT ISOWeek = (DY - 1) / 7 + 1
   ```

Here are the above calculations in a single statement:

```
SELECT ISOWeek = (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, Th) - 1) / 7 + 1
FROM (
  SELECT Th = DATEADD(DAY, 3 - (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @date) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7, @date)
) s;
```

Comment: +1 awsome, took me a while to realize what you were doing, so far I decided you are cheating, why didn't i think of that. I combined our answers to a very short compact solution.

Comment: Hi @AndriyM you will probably be one of the few people who can appreciate [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206736/eight-days-a-week/206765#206765) - imagine 8 days a week and using the same logic

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: Still figuring out all the details of the logic but that's incredible. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I should warn you, some of the answers I provided for code golf are not easy to understand

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: That's quite all right. When I fail to understand any of them, I know who to ask for help :) Cheers!

Answer (score 37):

There is a link here for other earlier attempts http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=60510

This is the OLD code for the function

```
CREATE function f_isoweek(@date datetime)
RETURNS INT
as
BEGIN
DECLARE @rv int

SELECT @rv = datediff(ww, dateadd(ww, datediff(d, 0, dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, day4),3))/7,-4),day4)
FROM (SELECT dateadd(ww, datediff(day, 0, @date)/7, 3) day4) a

RETURN @rv
END
```

After combining @AndriyM 's brilliant answer with my own, we are down to 1 line. This is the NEW code.

```
CREATE function f_isoweek(@date datetime)
RETURNS INT
as
BEGIN

RETURN (datepart(DY, datediff(d, 0, @date) / 7 * 7 + 3)+6) / 7
-- replaced code for yet another improvement.
--RETURN (datepart(DY, dateadd(ww, datediff(d, 0, @date) / 7, 3))+6) / 7

END
```

Explanation for the old code (not going to explain the new code. It is fragments from my code and AndriyM's code):

Finding weekday 4 of the chosen date

```
dateadd(week, datediff(day, 0, @date)/7, 3)
```

Finding isoyear - year of weekday 4 of a week is always the same year as the isoyear of that week

```
datediff(yy, 0, day4)
```

When adding 3 days to the first day of the isoyear a random day of the first isoweek of the isoyear is found

```
dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, day4),3)
```

finding relative week of the first isoweek of the isoyear

```
datediff(d, 0, dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, day4),3))/7
```

Finding the monday minus 4 days of the first isoweek results in thursday of the week BEFORE the first day of the first isoweek of the isoyear

```
dateadd(ww, datediff(d, 0, dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, day4),3))/7,-4)
```

Knowing first thursday of the week before the first isoweek 
and first thursday of the chosen week, 
makes it is quite easy to calculate the week, it doesn't matter which setting datefirst has since the weekdays of both dates are thursdays.

```
datediff(ww, dateadd(ww, datediff(d, 0, dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, day4),3))/7,-4),day4)
```

Comment: +1. Compared to this version http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx yours are multitudes better because it is not dependent on `set datefirst 1`.

Comment: Nice! And I like your `(n + 6) / 7` better than my `(n - 1) / 7 + 1`. Would have upvoted this again, if I could.

Comment: What if i want my weeks to start on Sunday?

Comment: @Martin iso weeks does not start on a sunday

Comment: This formula is awesome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Martin, i need to use the same formula concept for finding epiweek (http://www.cmmcp.org/epiweek.htm) which is slightly different as it starts on sunday; I just changed the choosing date as '1905-01-01' instead of '1900-01-01'~0 ; will that work as per your details...

SELECT (DATEPART(day,DATEDIFF(day,'1905-01-01',@day)/7*7+3)+6)/7

Answer (score 1):

Wow! Very good topic and solution to avoid using "set datefirst 1". I just want to add something. If like me, you also want to return the year with the ISO week, like "2015-01" as being "Year 2015, Week 01", it might be useful for reporting purpose. Since the year from ISO week can be different from the actual year of the date! Here is how I did in combination to your code.

```
DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME
SET @Date = '2014-12-31'
SELECT 
       CAST(CASE WHEN MONTH(@Date) = 1 AND Q.ISOweek > 50 THEN YEAR(@Date) - 1
                 WHEN MONTH(@Date) = 12 AND Q.ISOweek < 3 THEN YEAR(@Date) + 1
                 ELSE YEAR(@Date)
            END
            AS VARCHAR(4))
    + '-'
    + RIGHT('00' + CAST(Q.ISOweek AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2) AS ISOweek
FROM (SELECT (datepart(DY, datediff(d, 0, @Date) / 7 * 7 + 3) + 6) / 7 AS ISOweek) Q
```

Will return "2015-01".

Comment: I already wrote a simple script for iso_year.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829604/what-is-iso-year-in-sql-server/22830524#22830524

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar for PowerQuery & PowerBI and based on t-clausen.dk's response I was able to make this equation.  It works the same as his but uses PowerQuery syntax.  Also the base date for the `DATEDIFF` of 0 was 1/1/1900 in SQL but in PowerQuery it is 12/30/1899 so I use 2 instead of the 0.

```
ISO Week = Number.RoundDown((Date.DayOfYear(Date.From(Duration.Days(([Date]-Date.From(2))/7)*7+5))+6)/7)
```

I also needed the ISO Year so I made an adjustment to the ISO Week calculation and came up with:

```
ISO Year = Date.Year(Date.From(Duration.Days(([Date]-Date.From(2))/7)*7+3))
```

Change the `[Date]` to reference the date column in the data.