# (sql server 2005) How to determine the WEEK number starting from GETDATE()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting week number off a date in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348880/getting-week-number-off-a-date-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Please suppose (i am in Italy) that all the weeks start with `Monday` and end with `Sunday`.

I would like to write a scalar valued function that determines the `number of the week` with reference to `GETDATE()`

Thank you in advance for your kind cooperation.

PLEASE PAY ATTENTION TO THIS: The SELECT has to be INDIPENDENT from the SET DATEFIRST command!!

Comment: what do you mean the **Number** of the week ?

Comment: Do you want the number of weeks of a given timespan(f.e. `dbo.getNumWeeks(GetDate(), otherDate)`)?

Comment: No, sorry, I try to explain myself.  Last Monday (July 23rd, 2012) was the beginning of the 30th week, and the next Sunday (July 29th, 2012) will be the end of the 30th week.  This is in Italy.  In other countries, such as in America, the weeks start from SUNDAY and end with SATURDAY.

Comment: I need an unique select statement, indipendent from "set datefirst" command.

Comment: Try `datepart(iso_week, getdate())` It will change the weeknumber on Mondays.

Comment: 'iso_week' is not a recognized datepart option.

Comment: `iso_week` will work for you from SQL Server 2008. [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420(v=sql.100).aspx).

Comment: So this is for SQL Server 2005 or earlier?

Comment: This was the answer I was finding for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348880/getting-week-number-off-a-date-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: Great!  I'm glad that other answer also has a detailed explanation of the problems inherent in year-week numbers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little snippet that should do what you need.

```
DECLARE @firstOfYear DATETIME
SET @firstOfYear = STR(Year(GETDATE()), 4)+'-01-01 00:00:00'
SELECT DATEDIFF(ww, @firstOfYear - ((DATEPART(dw, @firstOfYear) + 5) % 7), GETDATE())
```

Keep in mind that if you want to set the week start to on a different day, just change the `+5` to the value based on `7 - dw`. This is for MSSQL.

This works by getting the first day of the year and finding the day of the starting week on or before that day. Then we get the number of weeks between whatever date was passed in and that "first" week start. If you want to allow any date to be passed in, just replace all `GETDATE` calls with your parameter and you should be good to go. If you need a single select statement:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(ww, day1 - ((DATEPART(dw, day1) +5) % 7), GETDATE()) 
FROM 
    (SELECT CAST(STR(Year(GETDATE()), 4)+'-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) day1) d
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your single select statement.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use the two liner?

```
  SET DATEFIRST 1;
  SELECT DATEPART( WEEK , GETDATE())
```

for today

```
SELECT DATEPART( WEEK , GETDATE())
```

returns 30 whereas

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
SELECT DATEPART( WEEK , GETDATE())
```

returns 31

**Edit** Untested but based on [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330711/isoweek-in-sql-server-2005) you can get the equivalent of the SQL Server 2008 `datepart(iso_week, getdate())` (which i believe is what you want) with the following select statement

```
SELECT ISOWeek = (DATEPART(DY, Th) - 1) / 7 + 1
FROM (SELECT Th = DATEADD(D, 3 - (DATEPART(DW, getdate()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7, getdate())) s
```

Comment: I am so sorry, I need a unique select statement...

Answer (score 0):

```
select datepart(week,getdate())
```

more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: select datepart(weeknum,getdate()) does not work, gives error

Comment: Does this account for the stipulation of Monday being the start of the week?

Comment: The select has to be indipendent from the SET DATEFIRST command, could you help me for this?  I've just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @oldDF int
set @oldDF = @@DATEFIRST

set DATEFIRST 1
select DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())

set DATEFIRST @oldDF
```

Comment: I need an unique select statement, how can I achieve this?