# Converting a PeriodStart and PeriodEnd to year + week number

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, script-component

I'm trying to convert a start + end date into multiple rows filled with weeknumbers and the year connected to it. My idea is to convert this start + end date in SSIS with a Script component, and create rows for each week by setting SynchronousInput to 'None'. I tried using a Timespan for this however this does not count through to the next year when reaching above week 53.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Example:

Input:

```
StartDate   EndDate
2014-12-29  2015-02-01
```

Wanted output:

```
  Year  WeekNr
  2015      1
  2015      2
  2015      3
  2015      4
  2015      5
```

Comment: There are 21 days between 5 and 26. How do you get 5 weeks? Is it full weeks starting on Monday or on StartDate?

Comment: corrected it but the point is to take the week number of the date (26 january is in week 5)

Comment: 2015-01-05 will never be week 1, not in ISO format, not in US format. Maybe you should describe exactly how to convert to your wanted output

Comment: well it actually is week 1 on the dutch calendar (http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2015&country=25&save=Show+%26+Save)

Comment: no, just checked, 2015-01-05 is week  2 in the dutch calendar. According to this [link](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/custom.html%3Fcountry%3D25%26lang%3Den%26lang2%3Dnl%26hol%3D9%26wno%3D1), it seems you are using the iso calendar

Comment: mhm was looking at the wrong year my bad

Comment: I would construct a calendar table - pre-populate that one time + yearly maintenance job on it as required then join to that based on start / end and pull out the week numbers you pre-calculated. This also allows you to deal with differences in how companies view the calendar (52 week vs 53 week). If you need contiguous numbers you can then use ranking functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I used the formular from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829604/what-is-iso-year-in-sql-server/22830524#22830524), but then remembered that, there is a better way using sqlserver 2008+ and changed the script to be more readable:

```
;WITH N(N)AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)),
tally(N)AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N.N)FROM N,N a,N b,N c,N d,N e,N f)
SELECT
  datepart(iso_week, dateadd(week, n-1, @from)) weeknr,
  datepart(year, dateadd(week, datediff(day, -7*n, @from)/7, -4)) Year
FROM TALLY
WHERE
  datediff(ww, dateadd(d, -1, @from), dateadd(d, -1, @to))+1 >= n
```

Result:

```
weeknr  Year
1       2015
2       2015
3       2015
4       2015
5       2015
```