# Partition over weeks in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have in table with two columns with dates. One date represent expected date and other one date when job is finished. I want to make query to get how many jobs were finished including specific week in current year and how many jobs should be finished to that week.

So if I transform my dates in weeks in those two colums as:

```
wkx:7,7,7,8,8,9,10,10,10,10,11,11
wkf:7,8,10,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
```

response should be smth like:

```
wk:7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
numx:3,5,6,10,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
numf:1,2,2,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

I am using SQL Server 2005, and have no idea even how to get distinct weeks in one column as is in example.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (?) might be to use an appropriate source of number to generate the interval of weeks and then do a conditional aggregation based of week number. The system table `master..spt_values` has a column that can be used for the week numbers and the week number for the `expected` and `finished` dates can be extracted using `datepart(wk, expected)` but that can give some odd results so I would recommend using the `dbo.f_isoweek()` function from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334148/1175077).

The function:

```
CREATE function f_isoweek(@date datetime)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (datepart(DY, datediff(d, 0, @date) / 7 * 7 + 3)+6) / 7
END
```

And the query would look like this:

```
select 
    week = number,     
    numx = sum(case when dbo.f_isoweek(expected) = number then 1 else 0 end),
    numf = sum(case when dbo.f_isoweek(finished) = number then 1 else 0 end),   
from master..spt_values, your_table 
where type='p' -- the type for the numbers in spt_values
  -- limit to current year
  and datepart(year, expected) = datepart(year, getdate()) 
  and datepart(year, finished) = datepart(year, getdate())
group by number 
-- limit weeks to available range (could be replaced with number between 1 and 53)
having number >= dbo.f_isoweek(min(expected)) and number <= dbo.f_isoweek(max(finished))
```

Given an input table like:

```
expected    finished
2015-01-05  2015-01-16
2015-01-06  2015-01-07
2015-01-18  2015-01-20
2015-01-25  2015-01-26
2015-01-26  2015-01-27
2015-02-08  2015-02-10
2015-02-10  2015-02-16
```

The output would be:

```
week    numx    numf
2       2       1
3       1       1
4       1       1
5       1       2
6       1       0
7       1       1
8       0       1
```