# Derive a Week ending Date from an existing column

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a table called Inventory, with one of the columns being report_dt, I want to add another column to the existing table called weekending_dt based on the report_dt. Report_dt : 20180108, 20180123, 20180129. Weekending_dt: 20180112, 20180126, 20180202.

If not able to add it to the same table I can make a copy of the table and add the columns to it. I need the logic to derive the Weekending_dt column. Thanks in advance your inputs are very much appreciated.

My initial approach was:
I thought of creating a table with 365 rows with dates (Jan through Dec) and deriving weekending_dt in the second column manually.
Then doing a lookup from the Inventory table of report_dt against the date column of the second table to pull it's corresponding weekending_dt.

I'm sure there is an easier approach. Once again appreciate all your inputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last day of last week in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924777/how-to-get-last-day-of-last-week-in-sql)

Comment: Thank you I shall build on that ... I got the idea.