# Getting the Last Day of the Previous Week SSIS Expression

Tags: ssis, expression, sql-server-data-tools

Could you please help me to find the last day (Sunday) of previous week?
I need to convert it to string because I need to have file name like "Test_2023_01_07".

I need to do it using an expression.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You should be able to use this in a SQL query window and populate your variable from there:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5925176/1459036    It looks like it would give you the last day of the current week, then you would just subtract 7 days from that.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on a US locale and there may be regional variations.

Solution is also based on [Andriy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5925176/1459036) excellent answer, HT to [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77794260/getting-the-last-day-of-the-previous-week-ssis-expression#comment137145123_77794260).

In SSIS expression language, we don't have the equivalent of `@@DATEFIRST` so this is hard coded to Sunday being `1`. You can test this by adding an Expression to a variable `DATEPART( "weekday", (DT_DATE) "2024-01-07" )`

I broke this down to several Variables as I wanted to ensure I was translating the answer correctly. It can be done in a single shot but I like to show my work.

- StartDate DateTime Value of `2024-01-10` Hardcoded to start with and eventually we'll use an Expression to get current date
- CurrentWeekDayNumber  Int32  Expression `DATEPART("weekday", @[User::StartDate])`  This will evaluate to 4
- DateOffset Int32 Expression `-1 - ( @[User::CurrentWeekDayNumber] +5) %7` This will evaluate to 4
- LastSunday DateTime Expression `DATEADD("DAY", @[User::DateOffset] ,  @[User::StartDate])`  This will evaluate to 2024-01-07

Modify the StartDate to any boundary conditions you want to check and then close and re-open the package. Everything should re-evaluate.

If you're happy with how that's working and you won't need to debug, you can write all of that as a single expression

- LastSundayInOne DateTime Expression `DATEADD("DAY", (-1 - ( @[User::CurrentWeekDayNumber] +5) %7), @[User::StartDate])`

The final step is to tie the StartDate to a real point in time. Many people reach for `GETDATE()` and I always advise against it. Every time you reference getdate, the value changes. Say your process starts today at 23:59:59. The first time you look at the StartDate variable it will say 2024-01-10. The package runs for 2 minutes. The final evaluation of StartDate will be 2024-01-11 because we ticked over the day mark. Maybe that will be fine, maybe not.

Instead, I advocate that people use `@[System::StartDate]` That variable is the time the package starts executing but it remains constant throughout package execution.

Finally, you want to make a date string using the yyyy_mm_dd,aka ccyy_mm_dd, pattern. That is going to use the pattern of

1. Get the numeric part of the date
2. Convert to string
3. Prepend a leading zero for month/day
4. Extract the final 2 characters
5. Concatenate those parts using the underscore

Variable: `FileDate` Data type String Expression is

```
(DT_WSTR,4)(year(@[User::LastSunday])) 
+ "-" 
+ RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)(month(@[User::LastSunday])),2)
+ "-" 
+ RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)(day(@[User::LastSunday])),2)
```

That evaluates to `2024-01-07`